# T4 Templates: How to create a subtemplate?

Tags: c#, templates, t4

Is there a way I can create a subtemplate within a template file in T4? I need to reuse a snippet of template within the same template and a embedded function does not allow template based reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use include.

```
<#@ include file="AnotherTemplate.tt" #>
```